# C++: Possible to code for ignoring const assignment?

Tags: c++, constants

I'm writing macros to reduce coding in a framework and am running into an issue where users have the option of entering a const qualifier. The issue is that later macro a value might be attempted to be assigned to the value. If the parameter is a const, I'd like the assignment to simply be ignored.

The simple macro below demonstrates what I'm up against:

```
#define DECLARE_AND_ASSIGN(type, param, init_val, later_val) \
type param = init_val; \
param = later_val;
```

The below works fine:

```
DECLARE_AND_ASSIGN( int, foo, 0, 42 )
```

But this obviously won't compile because a const is being assigned after initialization:

```
DECLARE_AND_ASSIGN( const int, bar, 0, 42 )
```

Is there a way to code the macro so the compiler will ignore const values being assigned? (Coding in C++ on VS2017)

Comment: I wonder when it would be OK to assign foo and leave bar alone

Comment: macros like this will reduce the maintainability of your code and make it less readable. could also mess up static analysis and IDE support. => do not do it

Comment: @skeller Not always. I assume the OP's example is minimised to the problematic parts and in reality contains other stuff too. If a part of code consistently uses a well-named, well-documented set of macros for reducing boilerplate, it can indeed *improve* readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the assignment with a helper like this:

```
template <class T, class A>
void assignNonConst(T &v, A &&a)
{
  v = std::forward<A>(a);
}

template <class T, class A>
void assignNonConst(const T&, A&&)
{}

#define DECLARE_AND_ASSIGN(type, param, init_val, later_val) \
type param = init_val; \
assignNonConst(param, later_val);
```

This way, when `param` is of non-`const` type, the first template overload is called and assignment happens. When `param` is `const`, the second overload is chosen and nothing is done.